# Visual Studio Debugging on Remote machine

Tags: python, visual-studio, debugging, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I am developing a python application to run on a raspberry pi. Obviously, I can't run visual studio on my raspberry pi. Is there any way to set up my pi (running raspbian) to be the debugging target, so that on my windows machine (with vs) I can write the code and get the output, but the code executes on the pi?

I've used visual studio to debug apps running on android, so I'm looking for something similar, and I would like if it were real time, so that debugging features such as breakpoints worked as well.

Edit for clarification: This already exists for c# and others, just looking for this for python: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/remote-debugging?view=vs-2019

Answer (score 0):

can you use putty on your windows machine to ssh connect to raspberry pi and run you code that way. You could use notepad++ or geanie to write your code on windows first or open the editor nano on raspberry pi to write your code.

Comment: Right, but I would like to write the code on my other machine.